# Rotate background image using sx props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to rotate a background image using the MU5 'sx' props syntax, I do not know how to do it and cannot seem to find the answer. I just want to rotate the background image, but not any child-components of the grid:

```
 <Grid container direction='column'sx={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${Image})`, transform: 'rotate(90deg)', backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
                    backgroundPosition: 'top left', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                }}>

  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `background-image` transformations, but if you dont want to rotate any child, you can work with pseudo element `::before`, add the background image and rotate, like this:

```
<Box
      sx={{
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        position: "relative",
        border: "dashed 3px royalBlue",
        overflow:'hidden',
        ":before": {
          content: "''",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: "-1",
          transform: "rotate(30deg)",
          backgroundImage:
            "url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScz4ccW2Mc2m5qU4rRicqn5lk7EN4qxsjLitrENxkiYPo7SC1hAkFd4BbTgxJhEov9iTc&usqp=CAU)"
        }
      }}
    >
      <Box sx={{ p: "10px", backgroundColor: "orange", color: "white" }}>
        Child 1 dddd
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ p: "10px", backgroundColor: "orange", color: "white" }}>
        Child 2 dddd
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ p: "10px", backgroundColor: "orange", color: "white" }}>
        Child 3 dddd
      </Box>
    </Box>
```